# onNewIntent is not called in JellyBean

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I see a difference in behavior of onNewIntent calls between 2.3.4 and 4.2.

I have an activity with `launchMode=singleTask`. According to my understanding of how singleTask works, each time when activity is restored from the task list, `onNewIntent` should be called.

This is what happens on 2.3.4 (LG P990) when I start an activity, press "home" to move it to foreground and then restore from task list (longpress "home"):

```
D/NewIntent(23314): onPause
D/NewIntent(23314): onNewIntent
D/NewIntent(23314): onResume
D/NewIntent(23314): onPause
D/NewIntent(23314): onNewIntent
D/NewIntent(23314): onResume
```

Same on 4.2 (Nexus 4):

```
D/NewIntent(12960): onPause
D/NewIntent(12960): onResume
D/NewIntent(12960): onPause
D/NewIntent(12960): onResume
```

As you see, onNewIntent is not called.

Can someone explain me what is going on?

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020909/bug-onnewintent-not-called-for-singletop-activity-with-intent-flag-activity-new?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a Galaxy Nexus on 4.2.2. The code was developed on an emulated Nexus S (API 15). I ended up moving the logic from onNewIntent() to onResume().

Comment: Yep, so far haven't found an answer and had to stop relying on onNewIntent call.

Answer (score 1):

During my headaches whilst trying to solve this dilemma [Re-showing-a-singletask-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351763/re-showing-a-singletask-activity) I had to create a "middle man" -- i.e. a separate (Self) IntentService which would receive a Bundle via its onHandleIntent method, and then immediately fire off a new intent (to your singleTask Activity).

I have just tested on devices running 2.3.7 and 4.1.2 - onNewIntent called on singleTask activity every time.

hth

Comment: I know that I shouldn't, but... thank you. I searched a lot to see if I could do this without using a service, but it seems there's no way. to think that all I wanted was for my activity to not be recreated when touching a notification if it was already on the top... anyway, not a big deal, since I already had a suitable IntentService that I created to handle another intent.