# (re) showing a singleTask activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I having some trouble with bringing a singletask activity back into view.

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".test.MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:icon="@drawable/my_launcher"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_my"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity=".myTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

MyActivity Code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
i.putExtra("blah", stuff);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // I have tried almost every flag combo here!
startActivity(i);
```

Scenario:

Upon onBackPressed() the activity calls moveTaskToBack (which hides my activity).
Upon receipt of a specific incoming event, the above intent code is called, however NOTHING happens!?! No OnNewIntent() fired, no onCreate fired...

HOWEVER:
If I also add a separate PendingIntent to a Notification object, it WORKS!?

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("blah", stuff);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notif = new Notification(icon,text,when);
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    m_notifMgr.notify(1, notif);
```

I don't understand why it works from a PendingIntent (firing onNewIntent), but not from a direct startActivity call.

Please advise. Thanks.

UPDATE (*1*):

I have simplified matters and placed the same logic into a small test app:

Activity 'A' = singleTask, with two buttons: btnStartTimer to start a timer, and btnMoveToBack to move 'A' to back.  When the timer expires, the intent to create 'B' is called.

Activity 'B' = plain 'hello world' screen.

Results:

(i) If I start the timer via btnStartTimer click, and do not press btnMoveToBack, then the intent code is called and 'B' appears.

(ii) If I start the timer via btnStartTimer click, and DO press btnMoveToBack, then the intent code is still called (indicated by log msg) and 'B' does NOT appear -- logging shows Activity 'B' onCreate NOT called.

Which raises the question -- can I actually get intents to be processed from an activity that is not shown?

Comment: Maybe not your problem but you should be using your `Activity`'s `Context` with `Intent` instead of `getApplicationContext()`. `Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class);`

Comment: Tried that. Behaviour remains the same.

Comment: Not really sure when your Intent/startActivity() code is run. Are you sure it is actually run at all? What kind of "event" are you waiting for? Aside: the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP should be enough. The FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK part is not needed, because a SingleTask Activity should always become the "root" Activity of a task (per definition).

Comment: I have logcat messages showing OK from before and after the startActivity call.  Additional log msgs at start of onCreate and onNewIntent methods not showing. Re: the event -- it is being generated from a third party API on receipt of an incoming SIP call -- this in turn triggers my code. Re: Intent flags -- I have used just about every flag combo there is (use of NEW_TASK was just the one I posted), including CLEAR_TOP on its own. Still the same. Baffled.

Comment: This is driving me insane. I only want to make a singleTask activity reappear after a call to moveTaskToBack!?! Is it use of a taskaffinity that is screwing this up? As a test, rather than trying to make my singleTask activity 're-appear', I tried launching a standard dummy activity from my singleTask -- that too will not show! Can I not launch activities with Intents (other than PendingIntent) from a singletask that has been 'moved to back'?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769255/769265 and the comment thread. This is an Android bug that was fixed in Android 4.4. Prior to that you could not bring your own app to the foreground by calling `startActivity()` on an Activity-Context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally cracked this one.  As it appears, an intent (with any consequence) cannot be fired from a paused (`singleTask`) Activity. Therefore my only option was to implement an `IntentService` (utilising `Intent` flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`) which in turn creates the required intent to 're-show' my `singleTask` Activity.

Seems like a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a walnut, but it is the only method I could find that worked.

Comment: Hi man, can you explain better what you have done to reshow your singleTask activity?

Comment: It appears that any non-`Activity` `Context` works. I got it working by calling `startActivity()` on the `Application` context, without needing a separate service or receiver.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769255/769265 and the comment thread. Prior to Android 4.4, you could not bring your own app to the foreground by calling `startActivity()` on an `Activity`. You needed to call `startActivity()` on another non-Activity `Context` (Application, Service, etc.). Since 4.4 it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent.hasExtra("KEY")) {
        int currentTab = intent.getIntExtra("KEY", 1);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTab);
    }
}
```

Comment: @arghtype onNewIntent is an  activity overrided method which is fired when a new intent is delivered to an already created activity.