# Method onNewIntent(intent) not executing in NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I am implementing the NFC in android project. I have written the entries which are required in the AndroidManifest.xml and Java code.

When any tag come near by device then my app detect the tag then it open the activity but here I am getting NFC Tag Info but `onNewIntent` is not executing.

Please guys share your views.

```
public class NFCActivity extends Activity {

    private NfcAdapter mNFCAdapter;
    private PendingIntent mNfcPendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc);

        // Create the OpenSqliteHelper object. It always best to create only
        // once instance of this OpenSqliteHelper
        DatabaseManager.init(this);

        mNFCAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        if (mNFCAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support NFC
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    getString(R.string.device_does_not_support_nfc),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (!mNFCAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                // NFC is disabled
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.enable_nfc),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(NFCActivity.this,
                        0, new Intent(NFCActivity.this, NFCActivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
            }
        }
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Tag mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mNFCAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mNFCAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcPendingIntent, null,
                null);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="net.livepatrols.thepartnerSA.NFCActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: try adding in activity tag android:launchMode="singleInstance" or android:launchMode="singleTop" if issue is related to onNewIntent, it'll solve

Comment: It is already singleTop `        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);` here

Comment: short version is - set the single top flag in both the intent and in the manifest. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020909/bug-onnewintent-not-called-for-singletop-activity-with-intent-flag-activity-new)

Comment: Not working I tried your views setting the android:launchMode="singleInstance" or android:launchMode="singleTop"

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto 's solution worked for me but don't know why...

Comment: @BurakKarakuş http://i.stack.imgur.com/6C8D9.gif

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code works fine when your activity is on foreground, but it won't work when the Activity is started by an Intent with `android.nfc.action.XXX_DISCOVERED` action. As it is the first intent, `onNewIntent()` won't be called, but you can use the intent in your `onCreate()` method. You should call your NFC logic from `onCreate()` and from `onNewIntent()`, validating the action before accessing the tag.

```
public class NFCActivity extends Activity {

    private NfcAdapter mNFCAdapter;
    private PendingIntent mNfcPendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        performTagOperations(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        performTagOperations(intent);
    }

    private void performTagOperations(Intent intent){
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED) ||
        action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) ){
            //PERFORM TAG OPERATIONS
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That makes no sense.  Why call `performTagOperations` twice?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - This approach doesn't call `performTagOperations` twice. This is covering two different scenarios. 1)When the activity is launched if a tag is detected and 2) when the activity is the foreground activity. Keep in mind that onNewIntent is only called if the activity is visible.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was, that I followed the documentation for `nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(...)` **blindly** and I pasted this code **into fragment**:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            new Intent(this, getClass())
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
```

Since it actually expects activity, just change all to this to `getContext()` and especially `getClass()`.

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getContext(),
            0,
            new Intent(getContext(), getContext().getClass())
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
```

Comment: `enableForegroundDispatch` requires activity as a param

Comment: set `getContext()` instead of `this` saved my day!

Comment: getContext() doesn't exist